# Delete Registry key from command line if match found

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line

How can I delete from regedit if the match found? 
For example,

there is an entry in a registry like 
HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\'smthing'.abc

Whatever the 'smthing' would be, I need to delete this key using commandline.

Comment: don't you have `REG` command?

Comment: I do have REG command but I need to delete the entry even if I don't know the whole name of the key.

Comment: and what about `WMIC` command?

Comment: Your explanation is not very good, Ranzan.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all values under a key with `REG DELETE <KEY> /va` if this is what you want. In your case:

```
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /va
```